# Referencing Shared Java EE Libs in Weblogic from WAR inside EAR

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, weblogic, shared-libraries

We have a number of applications that need to reference to both Oracle and our own Shared Java EE Libraries on WebLogic. They are structured as folows:

Our own shared library, "framework", is packaged as a JAR inside an EAR, along with all non-Oracle, third-party libraries (JAR:s) and deployed as a shared library in WebLogic.
This is it's manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.0.4
Built-By: lajokon
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_07
Implementation-Vendor: <organization>
Implementation-Title: Framework Lib
Implementation-Version: 15.0.2
Implementation-Vendor-Id: org
Specification-Vendor: <organization>
Specification-Title: Framework Lib
Specification-Version: 15.0.2
Extension-Name: framework-lib
```

All JAR:s are in APP-INF/lib

The applications are each packaged in a WAR inside its own EAR.
The WAR weblogic.xml:

```
<wls:weblogic-web-app>
    <wls:weblogic-version>10.3.6</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>app-name</wls:context-root>
    <wls:library-ref>
        <wls:library-name>adf.oracle.domain.webapp</wls:library-name>
        <wls:specification-version>1.0</wls:specification-version>
        <wls:exact-match>false</wls:exact-match>
    </wls:library-ref>
    <wls:library-ref>
        <wls:library-name>jsf</wls:library-name>
        <wls:specification-version>2.0</wls:specification-version>
        <wls:exact-match>false</wls:exact-match>
    </wls:library-ref>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

The EAR application.xml:

```
<application>
  <display-name>app-name</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>app-name.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/app-name</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

The EAR weblogic-application.xml:

```
<weblogic-application>
    <library-ref>
        <library-name>adf.oracle.domain</library-name>
        <specification-version>1.0</specification-version>
        <exact-match>false</exact-match>
    </library-ref>
    <library-ref>
        <library-name>coherence</library-name>
        <specification-version>3.7</specification-version>
        <exact-match>false</exact-match>
    </library-ref>
    <library-ref>
        <library-name>framework-lib</library-name>
        <specification-version>15.0</specification-version>
        <exact-match>false</exact-match>
    </library-ref>
</weblogic-application>
```

All libraries are deployed by default or deploy correctly in WL. As does the application EAR.

But, when I access the application i get runtime errors saying it can't load resources located in the WAR:s WEB-INF/classes dir!?

However, I can see, from log output, that it loads resources from the Framework EAR. Why does WL not seem to care about the contents of my WAR?

Comment: Could it be possible that the classes that are to be referred from WEB-INF/classes directory are instead being taken from APP-INF/lib of the shared EAR? If yes. Take a look at [prefer-application-packages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#autoId24), [prefer-web-inf-classes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#wp1067857) and [the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ArLTKapjV_8#t=306s)

Comment: Maybe, but there are no duplicate classes, that appear in both APP-INF/lib and WEB-INF/classes (application classes generally extend those from the framework package), if that is whar you mean..?

Comment: "when I access the application i get runtime errors saying it can't load resources located in the WAR:s WEB-INF/classes dir" - Can you give the complete error details?